# extending a url to another in django

Tags: python, django

I have a django application where by I can create a category and from the category I can select a subcategory before selecting a post. I have also created slugs for both the category , subcategory and the post and this works fine. what I now want to do but could not achieve is to make the subcategory slug continous on d category that is if the slug is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/house/` before clicking on a subcategory, I want the url to look like this after clicking on a post under house `http://127.0.0.1:8000/house/duplex` with dublex being a subcategory of the category house. below is my model for my sub 
category

**Models.py**

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='property', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400,db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=400,db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'subcategory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'subcategories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('subcategory:property_list_by_subcategory', args=[self.slug])
```

**View**

```
def index(request, subcategory_slug=None):
    subcategory = None
    subcategories = SubCategory.objects.all()
    properties = Property.objects.filter(available=True)
    if subcategory_slug:
        subcategory = get_object_or_404(SubCategory, slug=subcategory_slug)
        properties = properties.filter(subcategory=subcategory)

    context = {
        'subcategory': subcategory,
        'subcategories': subcategories,
        'properties': properties
    }
    template = 'subcategory/index.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<subcategory_slug>[-\w]+)/$',views.index, name='property_list_by_subcategory'),
]
```

additional codes would be supplied on request.

Comment: Did you try by making your post url like this -  `<sub-category>/<post>`. Then all you have to do is find the post and return it.

Comment: can you show me a demonstrated code please.

Comment: so that I can mark as correct.

Comment: Have you found a solution? If yes, you can just answer your question and mark your answer as accepted. If not, can you post your category url, sub-category url and post url?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I just noticed that you're serving two urls from a single view. So, Does that mean you want to serve the post url from this same view as well?

Comment: Yes. Kindly read the question again. I just modified it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162286/discussion-between-xyres-and-king).

Answer (score 0):

Create a third url like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<subcategory_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<property_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.post_view)
```

Then create a view for this url:

```
def post_view(request, subcategory_slug, property_slug):
    # find the subcategory
    subcategory = get_object_or_404(SubCategory, slug=subcategory_slug)
    # find the requested property
    property = get_object_or_404(Property, slug=property_slug, subcategory=subcategory)

   # do something else
   return render(request, template, context)
```